# No Such File Exception in java

Tags: java, file-io, nio

I'm having some problems with my program and it gives me `java.nio.file.NoSuchFileException`  I'm trying to copy folder and files to another but others are working as well. I'm trying to copy folder and files from the `Arraylist` the values from the arraylist was from the `DEL_COPY_DIR` which is properties file. This is my codes below.

```
   ArrayList<String> list1 = readConfigFileList(ConstantVariables.DEL_COPY_DIR);
                            for (String strList1 : list1)
                            {
                                if(strList1.contains("<mnbr>")){
                                    String[] saDirectory = strList1.split("<mnbr>");
                                    String strDirectory = saDirectory[0];
                                    String strMnbrContent = saDirectory[1];
                                    File file = new File(strSource + strDirectory);
                                    String[] saMnbrFile = file.list();
                                    for(int i = 0; i < saMnbrFile.length; i++) {

                                        File fileList = new File(strSource + strDirectory + saMnbrFile[i] + strMnbrContent);
                                        String strsrcList = new String(fileList.toString());
                                        File fileList1 = new File(strDestination + strDirectory + saMnbrFile[i] + strMnbrContent);
                                        String strdestList = new String(fileList1.toString());
                                        if(fileList.isDirectory())
//                                          System.out.println(strSource + strDirectory + saMnbrFile[i] + strMnbrContent);

                                            copyFolders(strsrcList, strdestList);
                                    }
                                }
                                else {
                                    copyFolders(strSource + strList1 , strDestination + strList1);
                                }
                            }
```

**Copy Files**

```
public void copyFiles(String source, String destination) throws IOException{

    try {
        File fileFrom = new File(source);
        File fileTo = new File(destination);
        Files.copy( fileFrom.toPath(), fileTo.toPath(), StandardCopyOption.REPLACE_EXISTING);

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        System.out.println("Error");

    }
}
```

**Copy Folder**

```
public void copyFolders(String src, String dest)
        throws IOException{
    File srcFrom = new File(src);
    File destTo = new File(dest);
    if(srcFrom.isDirectory()){
        if (!destTo.exists())
        {
            destTo.mkdir();
            txtDetails.append("Directory copied : " + dest + "\n");
        }
        final String files[] = srcFrom.list();
        for (String file : files)
        {
            File srcFile = new File(src, file);
            File destFile = new File(dest, file);

            //Recursive function call
            copyFolders(srcFile.toString(), destFile.toString());
        }

    }
    else{
        copyFiles(src, dest);
        txtDetails.append("Files Copying: " + srcFrom.getAbsolutePath() + "...Done" + "\n");

    }
}
```

**Full Error**

```
java.nio.file.NoSuchFileException: D:\dest\data\25\misc\AlarmCum.obj -> D:\destination\data\25\misc\AlarmCum.obj
at sun.nio.fs.WindowsException.translateToIOException(Unknown Source)
at sun.nio.fs.WindowsException.rethrowAsIOException(Unknown Source)
at sun.nio.fs.WindowsFileCopy.copy(Unknown Source)
at sun.nio.fs.WindowsFileSystemProvider.copy(Unknown Source)
at java.nio.file.Files.copy(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.wb.swt.FortryApplication.copyFiles(FortryApplication.java:295)
at org.eclipse.wb.swt.FortryApplication.copyFolders(FortryApplication.java:337)
at org.eclipse.wb.swt.FortryApplication.copyFolders(FortryApplication.java:332)
at org.eclipse.wb.swt.FortryApplication$3.widgetSelected(FortryApplication.java:239)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.TypedListener.handleEvent(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runDeferredEvents(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.wb.swt.FortryApplication.open(FortryApplication.java:51)
at org.eclipse.wb.swt.FortryApplication.main(FortryApplication.java:346)
```

PS: I'm using textbox for the source and destination

Comment: Does file `D:\dest\data\25\misc\AlarmCum.obj` exist? Does directory `D:\destination\data\25\misc` exist?

Comment: @Andreas yes on the file it exist but on the directory its not but others files are smoothly transferred but when that files it gives me error.

Comment: So, other files can be copied to other directories that exist, but this file cannot be copied to a directory that doesn't exist. Hmmm... I'm sorry. What is confusing you about the error message? The target directory doesn't exist, hence the error.

Comment: @Andreas other files are copied even though its not exist to the directory. I tried to print it out and its working but when I'm copying it its not. Sorry for the confusing question.

Comment: I'm still confused. You say the target directory doesn't exist, you get an error saying it doesn't exist, and you wonder what that means?

Comment: No, I'm just wondered why other files and folders are copied.. for example: i have `D:\dest\data\sample\sample.txt` that exist on the source folder and im going to transfer it to the destination folder which is empty and It copies.

Comment: *"to the destination folder which is empty"* So it **exists**. Copy to existing folder works. Copy to non-existing folder fails. What's so hard to understand about that?

Comment: I mean the `D:\destination` folder exist so basically it will copy because it's existing and then if its not i have a method there that it will create folder it its not exist.

Answer (score -3):

This exception means that attempt was made to access file which does not exist.
In your case it is `D:\dest\data\25\misc\AlarmCum.obj`.

I advise to check path for spelling errors and make sure it is on file system.

If you create file automatically make sure that it is created before accessing it.
Use this check

```
    if(yourFile.exists()){
    //your logic here
    }
else {
//your logic here when file doesn't exist
}
```

Comment: Error can also mean that target directory doesn't exist, and that's the case here, since [OP says the file does exist](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43199572/no-such-file-exception-in-java?noredirect=1#comment73471291_43199572).

Comment: Actually the file exist because i copied it from the original folder where I'm testing it to transfer to another, but anyways i'll gonna try what you said.

Comment: The file doesn't exist and error says that. Either path or file name is wrong

Comment: @JaySmith I'd check the path name and file name are the same.

Answer (score -3):

As exception says, the file does not exists at the path highlighted and you should try debugging your way.

Try to run your program with few files first, make it work and then move on to more generic number of files.

Comment: This should be a comment. It's not an answer.

Comment: The files are exist

Comment: Can you try checking permissions on this file then is it different from other files ? And also, can you rule out the possibility of this file not being used by any other program just to be on safer side.

Comment: Other folders that are included are being copied so it means that i have permission with that folder and I'm the only one who uses it. @PankajT